# How to show children popup windows as topmost if parent is topmost?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make sure that a popup window that is shown like this:

```
ChildWnd wnd = new ChildWnd();
wnd.ShowDialog();
```

is topmost if the parent window is topmost as well.

So why can't I do this?

```
partial class ChildWnd : Form
{
    public ChildWnd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.TopMost = this.Parent.TopMost;     //Why can't I use this?
    }
}
```

Comment: `wnd.ShowDialog(this);` <- Sets the Owner. `Parent` is `null` in your code.

Comment: If setting the Owner is not what is expected, add a Construtor that accepts a `bool`, e.g., `public ChildWnd(bool topMost) : this() => TopMost = topMost;`, then it becomes `using (var f = new ChildWnd(TopMost)) f.ShowDialog();`